# AngularJS list not showing - issue with custom filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to troubleshoot why my "upcoming events" list does not show? **[Live demo here](http://ogmda.com/sandbox/listings.html)** (code shown below)

**Here's my AngularJS view:**

```
<body ng-app="listApp">

<div class="container" ng-controller="EventController">

 <h3>Upcoming events:</h3>

    <ul ng-repeat="event in events | upcomingEvents | limitTo: 2">
        <li>{{ event.title }}</li>
        <li>{{ event.start }}</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**Here's my controller and a custom filter:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

var app = angular.module('listApp', []);

app.controller('EventController', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('events.json').success(function(data) { 
            $scope.events = data;
    })
});

    app.filter('upcomingEvents', function () {
     return function (input) {

    var upcomingEvents = [];

    upcomingEvents = input.filter(function (data) {
        var currentDate = new Date();

        if ((data.start - currentDate) >= 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

    upcomingEvents.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.start - b.start;
    });

    return upcomingEvents;
  };
});

</script>
```

**Here's my events.json feed:**

```
[
  {
    "title": "All Day Event",
    "start": "2015-07-13",
    "allDay": true
  },
  {
    "title": "Long Event",
    "start": "2015-07-05",
    "end": "2015-07-13"
  },
  {
    "title": "Repeating Event",
    "start": "2015-07-15",
    "allDay": false
  },
  {
      "title": "first time",
      "start": "2015-07-31"
  }
]
```

I am getting an error in Chrome's console, but not sure what it means.

**Console error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
at http://ogmda.com/sandbox/listings.html:44:31
at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://ogmda.com/sandbox/angularjs/angular.min.js:212:83), <anonymous>:2:191)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://ogmda.com/sandbox/angularjs/angular.min.js:117:376)
at n.$get.n.$digest (http://ogmda.com/sandbox/angularjs/angular.min.js:132:124)
at n.$get.n.$apply (http://ogmda.com/sandbox/angularjs/angular.min.js:135:269)
at http://ogmda.com/sandbox/angularjs/angular.min.js:19:437
at Object.e [as invoke] (http://ogmda.com/sandbox/angularjs/angular.min.js:39:156)
at d (http://ogmda.com/sandbox/angularjs/angular.min.js:19:358)
at Ac (http://ogmda.com/sandbox/angularjs/angular.min.js:20:151)
at Zd (http://ogmda.com/sandbox/angularjs/angular.min.js:18:464)
```

Anyone have any advice on how I can proceed to fix? Thanks.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with this line: if ((data.start - currentDate) >= 0)    Because they are different types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 if ((data.start - currentDate) >= 0)
```

to:

```
if ((new Date(data.start) - currentDate) >= 0)
```

The `data.start` is only string representation of date. Convert it to `Date` 1st

fixed Demo in <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1pzbdwdz/1/)**</kbd>

---

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

seems like in your code `input` value = `undefined` because on start you don't have `$scope.events` and
`input.filter(...)` fails.

so add something like in your filter:

```
var upcomingEvents = [];

if(!input){
 return upcomingEvents;
}
```

or initiate `$scope.events = []` in controller *(best bet)*

Comment: worked great! However, I still get a weird error in console after making that fix..actually its the same error as before. Should I be concerned?

Comment: do you mind taking a look at this follow up question related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395734/angularjs-list-with-custom-filter-not-sorting-correctly/31395810#31395810

Answer (score 1):

The error says that `input` the is `undefined`

```
upcomingEvents = input.filter(function (data) { //<-- error is here
```

Try checking for the value of `input` prior asking for the property `filter`

Answer (score 0):

The view and the controller are ok. You need to change the filter. Try this one:

```
.filter('upcomingEvents', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var upcomingEvents = [];
    upcomingEvents = input.filter(function(data) {
      var currentMs = (new Date()).getTime();
      var compareMs = (new Date(data.start)).getTime();

      if ((compareMs - currentMs) >= 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });

    upcomingEvents.sort(function(a, b) {
      return (new Date(a.start)).getTime() - (new Date(b.start)).getTime();
    });

    return upcomingEvents;
  };
});
```