# AngularJS list with custom filter not sorting correctly

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to figure out why my angularjS "latest upcoming events" list is not correctly showing the latest upcoming events. The order seems out of place.

**Out of place dated list:**  **[Live demo here](http://www.ogmda.com/sandbox/listings.html)**

```
Upcoming events:

Repeating Event
2015-07-16

Meeting
2015-07-26

Happy Hour
2015-07-19

Meeting at Google
2015-07-15
```

**Here is my view:**

```
<body ng-app="listApp">

<div class="container" ng-controller="EventController">

<h3>Upcoming events:</h3>

    <ul ng-repeat="event in events | upcomingEvents | limitTo: 4">
        <li>{{ event.title }}</li>
        <li>{{ event.start }}</li>
    </ul>
```

**And here is my controller with a custom filter to show the latest upcoming events based on current date:**

```
    var app = angular.module('listApp', []);

    app.controller('EventController', function($scope, $http){
        $http.get('http://www.ogmda.com/sandbox/fullcalendar/demos/json/events.json').success(function(data) { 
            $scope.events = data;
    })
});

    app.filter('upcomingEvents', function () {
 return function (input) {

var upcomingEvents = [];

 if(!input){
     return upcomingEvents;
    }     

upcomingEvents = input.filter(function (data) {
    var currentDate = new Date();

         console.log(new Date(data.start));

    if ((new Date(data.start) - currentDate) >= 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});

upcomingEvents.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.start - b.start;
});

 return upcomingEvents;
 };
});

app.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

The JSON feed looks like so:

```
 [
  {
  "title": "All Day Event",
  "start": "2015-07-11"
   },
   {
   "title": "Long Event",
   "start": "2015-07-07",
   "end": "2015-07-10"
   },
   {
   "id": "999",
   "title": "Repeating Event",
   "start": "2015-07-09"
    },
    {
    "id": "999",
    "title": "Repeating Event",
    "start": "2015-07-16"
    },
    {
    "title": "Meeting",
    "start": "2015-07-12"
    },
    {
    "title": "Conference",
    "start": "2015-07-11",
    "end": "2015-07-13"
    },
    {
    "title": "Meeting",
    "start": "2015-07-26",
    "end": "2015-07-30"
     },
     {
     "title": "Lunch",
     "start": "2015-07-12"
     },

     {
     "title": "Happy Hour",
     "start": "2015-07-19"
      },
      {
      "title": "Dinner",
      "start": "2015-07-12"
       },
       {
       "title": "Birthday Party",
        "start": "2015-07-04"
       },
        {
      "title": "Meeting at Google",
      "url": "http://google.com/",
      "start": "2015-07-15"
       }
       ]
```

Any tips so I can try to troubleshoot this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to filter the items by the start dates in descending order, you can use orderBy:

```
 <ul ng-repeat="event in events | upcomingEvents |orderBy:'-start'| limitTo: 4">
        <li>{{ event.title }}</li>
        <li>{{ event.start }}</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Need to do it based on the current date. So if today is july 13, the latest events shown should only be july 14, 15, etc.

Comment: I misunderstood your message. It worked great. Thanks